# set_fact create a list with items

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have task which calls an API and I register the o/p in a  varaible;

```
- name: Get Object storage account ID
  uri:
    url: 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/getAllObjects.json?objectFilter={"username":{"operation":"{{ item }}"}}'
    method: GET
    user: abxc
    password: 66c94c447a6ed8a0cf058774fe38
    validate_certs: no
  register: old_existing_access_keys_sl
  with_items: '{{ info["personal"].sl_cos_accounts }}'
```

old_existing_access_keys_sl holds:

```
"old_existing_access_keys_sl.results": [
 {
            "json": [
                {
                    "accountId": 12345, 
                    "id": 70825621, 
                    "username": "xyz-11"
                }
            ]
},
{
            "json": [
                {
                    "accountId": 12345, 
                    "id": 70825621, 
                    "username": "abc-12"
                }
            ]
}
```

I want to make a list of `id`'s for further processing an tried the following task but this did not work:

```
- name: Create a list of account ids
  set_fact: 
    admin_usernames = "{{ item.json[0].id | list }}"
  with_items: old_existing_access_keys_sl.results
```

I am not sure if that's even possible. I also tried this:

```
    - name: create a list
      set_fact:
         foo: "{% set foo = [] %}{% for i in old_existing_access_keys_sl.results %}{{ foo.append(i) }}{% endfor %}"
```

foo always comes as blank and as a string:

```
TASK [result] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example data, you can extract a list of ids using the `json_query` filter, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    old_existing_access_keys_sl:
      results:
        [
          {
            "json": [
              {
                "accountId": 12345,
                "id": 70825621,
                "username": "xyz-11"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "json": [
              {
                "accountId": 12345,
                "id": 70825621,
                "username": "abc-12"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: old_existing_access_keys_sl|json_query('results[*].json[0].id')
```

This will output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "old_existing_access_keys_sl|json_query('results[*].json[0].id')": [
        70825621, 
        70825621
    ]
}
```

If you want to store these in a new variable, you can replace that `debug` task with `set_fact`:

```
    - set_fact:
        admin_ids: "{{ old_existing_access_keys_sl|json_query('results[*].json[0].id') }}"
```

**Update**

For a list of dictionaries, just change the `json_query` expression:

```
- debug:
    var: "old_existing_access_keys_sl|json_query('results[*].json[0].{id: id, username: username}')"
```

For more information, see the [jmespath website](http://jmespath.org/) for documentation and examples.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but got this too: `{"msg": "You need to install \"jmespath\" prior to running json_query filter"}`. Had to install this first using pip.

Comment: That's correct, some ansible modules and filters have prerequisites that may or may be installed by default. It depends on how you install Ansible and what sort of dependencies are configured by your installation tools.

Comment: I've added an example that creates a list of dictionaries, and links to additional information about the jmespath query language used by the `json_query` filter.